# Pass list value to view model class variable in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I need to pass list of records to class variable (Users and Groups) in view model but I cannot seeing view model object (_UserAndGroupModel) recognizing its class object, I am not sure exactly what I am missing here.

### ViewModel

```
 public class UserGroup_ViewModel
{
    public User Users { get; set; }
    public Group Groups { get; set; }
}
```

each class user and group have their variables and collection Items

In following lines of code I need to pass list and and assign to user object and groups object within the view model

```
 public partial class UserManagement_Services 
{
    List<UserGroup_ViewModel> _UserAndGroupModel = new List<UserGroup_ViewModel>();

    public void GetUserAndGroups()
    {
        using(var _uow = new UserManagement_UnitOfWork())
        {
            _UserAndGroupModel.Users= _uow.User_Repository.GetAll();
            _UserAndGroupModel.Groups = _uow.Group_Repository.GetAll();

         //error here   ??????????????
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

### Controller Method

```
  public ActionResult AddUserInGroup()
    {
        var _UserAndGroupList = _userServices.GetUserAndGroups();

        return PartialView("AddUserInGroup_Partial", _UserAndGroupList);
    }
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<App.DAL.Model.UserGroup_ViewModel>
```

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model)
            
            
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            
            
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
            
            
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailAddress)

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {....
```

In view I cannot see ViewModel class variable when I do model => model.????

Comment: Don't use `var`, if you know that `_userServices.GetUserAndGroups()` returns a `UserGroup_ViewModel` then use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have done it a little different. You want to return a single view model to the view consisting of a list of users and a list of groups (please correct me if I am wrong). I would have  initialised the lists to empty (containing no items) in the constructor of the view model:

```
public class UserGroup_ViewlModel
{
     public UserGroup_ViewlModel()
     {
          Users = new List<User>();
          Groups = new List<Group>();
     }

     public List<User> Users { get; set; }

     public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your service layer you contruct the view model and populate the users and groups, and then return the view model to the calling method, in this case I would assume the controller's action method:

```
public class UserManagement_Services
{
     public UserGroup_ViewModel GetUserAndGroups()
     {
          UserGroup_ViewModel _UserAndGroupModel = new UserGroup_ViewModel();

          using(var _uow = new UserManagement_UnitOfWork())
          {
              _UserAndGroupModel.Users = _uow.User_Repository.GetAll();
              _UserAndGroupModel.Groups = _uow.Group_Repository.GetAll();
          }

          return _UserAndGroupModel;
     }
}
```

Just make sure that `User_Repository.GetAll()` and `Group_Repository.GetAll()` have a return type of `List<User>` and `List<Group>`.

And then your controller might look something like this:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
     private IUserManagement_Services userManagementService;

     public UserController(IUserManagement_Services userManagementService)
     {
          this.userManagementService = userManagementService;
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          // The service will return a view model already populated with the users and groups
          UserGroup_ViewlModel model = userManagementService.GetUserAndGroups();

          return View(model);
     }
}
```

In your view you would have the following, accept the view model passed in by the action method and display the users and groups:

```
@model MyProject.Models.UserGroup_ViewlModel

 <table>
      <thead>
           <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Groups</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
           @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
           {
                <tr>
                     <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                     <td>@user.LastName</td>
                     <td>
                          <select>
                               @foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
                               {
                                    <option>group.GroupName</option>
                               }
                          </select>
                     </td>
                </tr>
           }
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

The code above has not been tested at all, there might be a couple of issues with the @ symbol in the view. I can see what you are trying to get at. A list of users in a table, then per line you want a dropdown list of user groups that you want to select and then send back to the controller. That is out of scope for this post, start a new one. I have helped you on the correct track, you just need to spend some more time reading up on ASP.NET MVC.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: That is correct, in addition my GetAll() method is returning IQueryable and I am getting another issue to populate model in view from viewmodel

Comment: What is your issue? Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Give me min I upload screen shot

Comment: I cannot access to Users and Groups from viewmodel in view. My view is strongly typed with view

Comment: I updated controller and view code in my question above

Comment: Check my updated answer where I loop through the users and groups in the view.

Comment: why I cannot do model.Users.FirstName as like... other variables??

Comment: also I need to mix user and group in table within same line ... i.e. drop down group list.

Comment: Work from my example. You cannot use `model.Users.FirstName' because Users is a list. You need to access each user in the list, then you can use first name. Check my answer in the view.

Comment: Check my updated answer. More than this I cannot help because you did not accept my answer as the answer :)

Comment: many thanks for all your help ... really appreciate ... I have accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Your error is stems from this line

```
List<UserGroup_ViewModel> _UserAndGroupModel = new List<UserGroup_ViewModel>();
```

`_UserAndGroupModel` is a `List`, so when you set with

`_UserAndGroupModel.Users = ..`.

this is invalid becuase `Users` is a property of an **item** in the list, not the list itself.

However, this

```
_UserAndGroupModel.First().Users = ...
```

would work for example.

Comment: then how I assign list in GetUserAndGroups() method??

Comment: @toxic, by changing your ViewModel like my suggestion above. It should then stop giving you an error. Let me know if it still does

Comment: No I am still getting error, I have upload screen shot of error in my question

Answer (score 0):

here is answer and many thanks to Ammar for help!

```
public class UserGroup_ViewModel
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }

}
```

.

```
public UserGroup_ViewModel GetUserAndGroups()
    {
        using(var _uow = new UserManagement_UnitOfWork())
        {
            _UserAndGroupModel.Users = _uow.User_Repository.GetAll().ToList();
            _UserAndGroupModel.Groups = _uow.Group_Repository.GetAll().ToList();

            return _UserAndGroupModel;
        }

    }
```